# Attributed string 'Google' contains NSLinkAttributeName. Removed

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, wkinterfacelabel

I am developing application in apple Watch. I am using label and adding text as link. On that link i want to implement phone call event.
I am using following code.

```
[string addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName
                   value:linkURL
                   range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];
```

but I am getting following error.

```
Attributed string '9618194xxx' contains NSLinkAttributeName. Removed
```

please help me out

Thanks in Advance

Comment: "I am getting error" please elaborate

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe WatchKit supports links in attributed strings. Since there's no browser on the Watch, tapping it wouldn't open anything anyway.